# Yii framework 2.0 data from database for input field select options

Tags: php, database, yii2

With Yii framework 1, when I get data from the database and want to put key-values to the input field select options, I use this code in the controller:

```
$roleDataProvider = CHtml::listData(Role::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'description');
```

When working with Yii framework 2.0, I don't have the CHtml::listData(). What should I use to approach the same result? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $dataList=ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->withoutSubs()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($dataList); ?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how your solution works, to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

@Arkanon: here is the usage related to the above code. In your controller:

```
$dataList = ArrayHelper::map(ModelClass::findOne($id)->all(), 'column_id', 'column_username');
$model = new ModelClass();
return $this->render('viewpage', ['modelXX' => $model, 'keyZZ' => $dataList]);
```

In your viewpage.php:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-id']);
$form->field($modelXX, 'user_id')->dropDownList($keyZZ, ['class' => 'class_name', 'id' => 'id_name']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

Now you should have a dropdownlist, filled with data coming from the database. The value of the dropdownlist is 'column_id' and the label of the dropdownlist is 'column_username'.